Could Prop be the top universe?
In the type theoretic domain (and I am specifically interested in constructive systems, should this be relevant to my question: I am not sure), AIUI, a typical hierarchy of universes looks like this:
(Prop + Set + Type1 + Type2 + ... + TypeN) for all N.
Has anyone investigated the following instead:
(Set + Type1 + Type2 + ... + TypeN + Prop) for all N.
i.e. with Prop at the top of the hierarchy?
Is there anything along that line?  (Does it even make sense/could it work?  With Univalence?)
My motivating intuition being that in Type we build things (structures), in Set we can also compute with things, on the other hand in Prop we talk about all those things.
Thanks in advance for any hint or insight.

Well, the point of that hierarchy is that it's cumulative in some sense, i.e. that any Prop is also a Type. If you flip them you don't get a cumulative hierarchy any more, because every Type is not a Prop (it can be reflected as a Prop if you truncate it, but that's not usually how cumulativity is understood).

And also, it is not clear what "top" means when the hierarchy is not cumulative. Being at the top is equivalent to just being disjoint, so you could as well say Prop is to the side, rather than the top.

I was reading around that cumulativity is not the only option for a universe hierarchy, predicativity can achieve similar results, and there is also the issue of Type in Type or not: but I am still far from having a clear picture.  My basic idea for lifting terms to Prop is that judgments can easily be seen as propositions...

Conjecturally: Hindley-Milner upside down for a universe hierarchy with Prop on top.


Prop at the top of the hierarchy?  Is there anything along that line?

AFAICT, no.  Indeed, not only Prop is invariably rather found at the botton of type hierarchies, there is in fact no proof assistant that implements a closed type hierarchy at all.
Which, I'd propose, reflects the ubiquitous use of standard set theory in the development of these languages and systems: and the switch to homotopic does not seem to have changed that.  For the semantics of a closed system (as in closure), rather see positive set theory.

The proof assistant community apparently doesn't know anything about non-standard anything...

You specifically asked if Prop could be the top universe, which is not at all the same question as "are there proof assistants that place Prop at the top".  Consequently, the question cannot be answered by observing what is done in practice.

"could" is the keyword there?  What are even talking about??   And why immediately the personal attack and nothing else?  You too cannot stand being told you are wrong or that you don't know it all?

What personal attack? I am reading your question as: theoretically speaking, is it possible to have a type theory such that there is a top universe of propositions that contains an infinite hierarchy of universes? This is a theoretical question. If you are asking why proof assistants put Prop at the bottom, that's a different question.

By the way, what do you mean by "closed type hierarchy"?

I asked about "Prop as the top universe", your answer is neither about Prop nor about top, except marginally maybe...  Indeed, your answer is as sloppy and incorrect as it is useless and totally misleading, I can actually say that much.  -- As for closure, you don't need a definition from me, you should just read more carefully, and maybe open that link to "positive set theory", might even be interesting...  (EOD: I have lost the last bit of faith I had here.)

I am familiar with positive set theory. I think it is fair to ask how you would translate the closure condition to type theory, given that there is no notion of subset/subclass, nor global memebship, in type theory.

In any case, I don't think there is any point in continuing this discussion.

If and how to a closure condition for type theory is essentially my question.  And, since you ask, here is my best guess at this point: of course, as you mentioned, have Type_w only on the right of the colon (and make it into Prop with proof irrelevance, and/or impredicativity? or maybe Prop just on top of the whole thing? I am still sorting out details), and the problem remains only at the level of semantics: so, use a different "model"...  (No?)

And, FWIW, what's actually interesting to me is that somehow, as for semantics and primitives, we are always back to "sets" and just sets.  --  And why not just (a "closed") extensional type theory then?  --  I'll have to rewatch all intros to Univalence: why formal I easily get, why homotopic I can no more understand.

I am going to interpret your + as "is an element of", i.e., you are asking for a hierachy of universes that looks like this:
$$\mathsf{Set} : \mathsf{Type}_1 : \mathsf{Type}_2 :\mathsf{Type}_3 : \cdots : \mathsf{Prop}$$
We are not requiring cummulativity.
If we require nothing of $\mathsf{Prop}$ other than it being a universe, then we can just set $\mathsf{Prop} = \mathsf{Type}_\omega$, which is perfectly doable (Agda has this).
We usually make further assumptions about $\mathsf{Prop}$, such as:

Impredicativity: for any type $A$ (in any universe) and $P : A \to \mathsf{Prop}$, the product $\prod_{a : A} P a$ is in $\mathsf{Prop}$.
Propositional extensionality: for any $P, Q : \mathsf{Prop}$, if $P \leftrightarrow Q$ then $P = Q$.
Uniqueness of proof: for any $P : \mathsf{Prop}$ and $u, v : P$ we have $u = v$.

We cannot reasonably assume propositional extensionality, because it forces all the universes to be equal (since $\mathsf{Type}_i$ and $\mathsf{Type}_j$ are inhabited, we have $\mathsf{Type}_i \leftrightarrow \mathsf{Type}_j$).
We cannot reasonably assume uniqueness of proofs, because that would mean each universe $\mathsf{Type}_i$ has at most one element.
Can we assume that $\mathsf{Prop}$ is impredicative? That's an interesting question! I am inclined to answer positively. Here's an idea on how to construct a model. Familiarity with realizability theory is going to be assumed, as I am not going to write a paper here.
Recall that, given a partial combinatory algebra $A$, the category of assemblies $\mathsf{Asm}(A)$ contains an impredicative universe $\nabla\mathsf{Per}(A)$. If we can arrange for $\nabla\mathsf{Per}(A)$ to contain lots of smaller universes, that will do the job. We can do so if we take a huge pca $A$ whose size is so big that it contains lots of sets $V_\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is inaccessible. So let $\kappa$ be a cardinal below which there are at least countably many inaccessibles. Take the pca $A$ to be Scott's graph model $\mathcal{P}(V_\kappa)$ (application is still defined in the exact same way as in the usual Scott's model $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$). Then each $V_\lambda$ with inaccessible $\lambda < \kappa$ appears as partial equivalence relation in $\nabla\mathsf{Per}(\mathcal{P}(V_\kappa))$, namely the equality relation restricted to $V_\lambda$. If anyone checks the details, please let us know.

But don't you already know the difference between $\in$ and $\subseteq$ in set theory? It's the same thing.

Of course, $U^-$ shows that you cannot "stack" impredicative universes. I wonder if you can have them if you have an "intermediate" predicative universe...

It's the "Girard paradox" system, where you have 2 impredicative universes $$ and $\square$ with $ : \square$.

@cody Nothing in that system says there isn't an intermediate universe, so there could be one and it wouldn't affect the proof of the paradox.

Sorry, still elaborating this, I miss a last piece:  What is the type of $\mathsf{Type}{\omega}$?  Namely, if it is the top of the hierarchy, isn't it necessarily $\mathsf{Type}{\omega} : \mathsf{Type}_{\omega}$?  And is that consistent, maybe under further constraints?  (I know of positive set theory, though this is type theory, so I am not sure how it goes here.)

Why would $\mathsf{Type}\omega$ have to have a type? Only terms have types, and there is no situation in which $\mathsf{Type}\omega$ acts as a term, so the question of its type never comes up. Or to put it another way $\mathsf{Type}_\omega$ only appears on the right-hand side of the "typing colon $:$". There is no requirements that every type should be contained in some universe...

... What probably confuses you is that some popular type theories do have the property that every type is contained in a universe, and those are the ones you have seen. (They're the ones that I was explaining in Everything you wanted to know about type universes but were afraid to ask. But in Martin-Löf type theory we have a special judgement $\vdash A \ \mathsf{is-type}$ which means "$A$ is a type", and it's separate from $e : A$.

<<$\mathsf{Type}_\omega$ only appears on the right-hand side of the "typing colon $:$>>  Hmm, I see, though I can understand the mechanics, not really make sense of it: anyway this gets beyond the scope of the present question...  BTW, I am sorry, I have mistakenly said type instead of universe in my previous comment.  But never mind, thank you for your reply and the reference, you have given me plenty to work with: I might be able to ask more specific questions later.

The original Martin-Lof papers on type theory has no universes, see for instance page 3 of Intuitionistic Type Theory  (Bibliopolis notes). What you know as "$A : \mathsf{Type}_i$" is "$A$ is a set" there.

<<we can just set $\mathsf{Prop} = \mathsf{Type}_\omega$, which is perfectly doable (Agda has this).>> I cannot actually find that anywhere in Agda, I rather find $\mathsf{Prop}_0 = \mathsf{Set}_1$ etc.  In particular, AFAICT, Agda as all the others does not have a type of all types, i.e. there is no "top" universe, whether $\mathsf{Prop}$ or other. -- Indeed, for all I have seen to this point, the only set theory that is used at all levels, including semantic/model-theoretic, is the standard one and nothing else, with its treatment of infinities...

I meant that Agda has $\mathsf{Type}\omega$, and that we could interpret $\mathsf{Prop}$ as $\mathsf{Type}\omega$ (if we wanted to). Agda does not actually have Prop as a defined entity.

But I do find $\mathsf{Prop}$ in Agda, in particular see here: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/prop.html#the-predicative-hierarchy-of-prop  Also, I would understand "interpreting $\mathsf{Type}_{\omega}$ as $\mathsf{Prop}$", not the other way round.

Plus, Agda does have a $\mathsf{Type}{\omega}$ (actually a $\mathsf{Set}{\omega}$: are we talking about the same thing?), but it is not the top of the hierarchy: "$\mathsf{Set}_{\omega}$ is itself the first step in another infinite hierarchy", see https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/universe-levels.html#expressions-of-sort-set  --  Indeed they even say the usual "But if Agda were to support a sort Sort of all sorts, it would be a sort itself, so in particular we would have Sort : Sort. Just like Type : Type, this would leads to circularity and inconsistency."

Ah, yes, the strict Prop. That's fairly new. It doesn't matter. Don't worry about what is and isn't found in proof assistants. You asked a specific question, I answered. I don't know why we're still discussing things.

Your answer is as sloppy and incorrect as it is useless and totally misleading, I can actually say that much.  You should delete it: which is the normal advice for users in these cases.  For now you get my downvote, not any pointless "discussion", or maybe you prefer a link to what $\in$ means?  Unbelievable...

Which part of my answer, specfically, is incorrect (not the comments, I am asking about the answer. In the comments I did incorrectly state that Agda has no Prop.)? And there is no need to be insulting. If you were offended by anything I said, I apologize.

I am not insulting anybody, please.

Your comment ridiculing me for not knowing what $\in$ means is insulting, and so is your comment that "the entire proof assistant community doesn't know anything about non-standard anything...".
